# BitSet from byte[] with strange lenght

Tags: java, bitset

my code is :

```
String blah = "blah";
byte[] blahBytes = blah.getBytes("US-ASCII");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(blahBytes));
BitSet set = BitSet.valueOf(blahBytes);
System.out.println(set.length());
```

the output is :

```
[98, 108, 97, 104]
31
```

Why is `length()` returning 31? Shouldn't it be 32?

Comment: My mistake ... I second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit set length is determined by the position of the highest bit set to `1`. Since all bytes that you pass to construct bit set represent ASCII character subset of UNICODE, the 8-th bit is always zero. Therefore, the highest bit set to `1` will be either bit 30 or bit 31, depending on the letter or digit in the end of your string: if you pass `"bla1"` instead of `"blah"` you would get 30 ([demo 1](http://ideone.com/dh6RTU)). If you use control characters, such as `<TAB>` you could get an even shorter bit set of 28 ([demo 2](http://ideone.com/H6pqhw)).

If you would like to get a length rounded up to the next multiple of 8, use

```
int roundedLength = 8 * ((set.length() + 7) / 8);
```

[demo 3](http://ideone.com/syLlOJ)

Comment: exactly it would be (8 bits) + (8 bits) + (8bits) + (7bits) because the last character in 'blah' is 'h' wich has the decimal unicode '104' in binary it is '01101000' so the bit with the highest bit set to 1 is the 7th bit so it only cosider it 7 bits long '0->(1)101000'